Implicit differential equations and degenerate metrics
I am currently exploring systems of implicit differential equations of the first and second order and seeking resources to better understand them. My interest arises in the context of a manifold with a degenerate metric. In such a case, when one naively attempts to derive the equations for parallel transport or geodesics, a challenge arises: it is not possible to solve for the highest-order derivatives explicitly. Consequently, the standar theorem about existence and uniqueness does not apply in this situation.
This is the first time I have encountered such a mathematical object, and I am unsure where to begin my study. I would greatly appreciate any guidance, references, or advice you can provide.
Thanks you for your time.
